# Desktop application to manage cloud storage services

Tags: windows, file-synchronization, synchronization

I'm looking for an application that will wrap other cloud storage services (Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox, etc.), and will allow customized syncing, similar to [odrive](https://www.odrive.com/).

Currently I'm using odrive free version, and the thing I'm missing is rules for files/folders I don't want to sync. This feature is available on the paid version, but it's to expensive for me.

Is there a free or cheap alternative, that also has [those features from odrive free version](https://www.odrive.com/upgrade), that includes rules?

I prefer it to be free, but I can afford myself a cheaper subscription of around 1-2$ a month.

**Hard requirements:**

- Rules to ignore files/folders
- Partial syncing/unsyncing
- Supports at least Google Drive, OneDrive and Dropbox
- Will be the only cloud-syncing application I'll need on my computer

**Nice but (absolutely) not must:**

- Open source
- CLI control
- Web interface in addition